# Vanilla JavaScript toggle element with text to editable element on edit button click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm trying to make my first vanilla JavaScript app which is (surprisingly :D) To-Do App
I'm currently stuck with the update todo part,
I got this part of code doing to-do creation

```
let createTodo = (todo) => {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('text');
  spanParent.prepend(span);
  span.innerHTML += `${todo.text}`;

  let edit = document.createElement('span');
  edit.classList.add('edit');
  spanParent.append(edit);
  edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

  let editIcon = document.createElement('i');
  editIcon.classList.add('fa-solid');
  editIcon.classList.add('fa-pen-to-square');
  edit.prepend(editIcon);
};
```

I want that when user click edit the todo text turn to editable input and save new value on enter or clicking outside and it become not editable again until pressing edit

I did some research and come across (contentEditable) attribute , but when tried to apply it things went sideways,

- when i turn it on the edit icon disappear and the text stay editable
- i think i need to do some kind of form that show on edit but don't know how to approach this idea

**EDIT**
I'll try to explain more clearly hopefully,
I need to make the to-do text to be:
1- editable when user click the edit button
2- save the new user input text
3- become non-editable once user save updates
4- become editable again if user press edit button again

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, but feel that I can help you out. Maybe try to be a bit more precise.

Comment: What I understand is that you need some kind of a feature that allows the to-do text to be editable when an edit button is clicked, and then the text should become non-editable once a click is made outside the editable region. Is that it?

Comment: sorry i ll try to be a bit more clear hopefully, yes i need to make the to-do text to be - editable when i click the edit button, - save the new user input text, - become non-editable once user save updates

Comment: So you have a SAVE button as well. Right?

Comment: What problem are you currently facing? Are you unable to implement the click handler of the EDIT button or is there another problem?

Comment: yes atm i made a form that i hide and show but my problem is passing and changing text data, also input keep refresh even though i add event to prevent default

Comment: How do you save the to-do text? Do you send it to the server or you store it locally?

Comment: trying to save locally

Comment: Alright, in that case, I don't think that you need a form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description that you provided, there is technically no need of using a form. You could stick to a standalone button and give it a click handler.

The click handler of this EDIT button works as follows: it sets the `contenteditable` attribute on the to-do text element (the `span` element above). This makes the text editable.

Then when the SAVE button is pressed, you should do the following: get the `textContent` of the `span` element, store it locally (I guess you're using `localStorage`) and then finally remove the `contenteditable` attribute from the `span` element.

---

BTW, I feel that there is a lot of room of improvement in your code, for e.g. in variable naming, in the usage of methods, and in the order of statements:

1. `append()` and `prepend()` is, more or less, meant for bulk-insertion of nodes into the DOM. In your case, you have just one single node to add and so you could just stick to using `insertBefore()` or `appendChild().
2. Most probably, the to-do text is styled as a block in your application. Hence, it's better to make it a `<div>` element, instead of a `<span>`.

There is an awesome resource to learn about the HTML DOM, along with exercises to practice your skills: [HTML DOM Introduction — CodeGuage](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/html-dom-introduction).

Comment: Thanks alot realy appreciate you taking time to help it took serval try's and tweaks but i finally got it to work, 
there's just one wired thing happening, although i added  `contenteditable` to the exact text container it also make the button text editable

Comment: Also thanks for the general advices and the resource link,
but i wonder do i need to dive deep in DOM world if im going to shift to React?

Comment: @MaximoConn yes absolutely you do need to learn the DOM really well before moving on to React. Technically, you won't directly be working with the DOM in React — the library will do this on its own — but you'll understand everything much better and how the virtual DOM, in React, works if you understand the DOM well.